# Exclude weekends in delivery date

Tags: vb.net, datetime

I have a code that gets an ETA (estimated time of arrival) but I want it to exclude weekends. I also have it to change the ETA if its past 2:30PM.

Code:

```
    Dim ETA1 As Date = Date.Today.AddDays(1)
    Dim ETA2 As Date = Date.Today.AddDays(2)
    Dim ETA3 As Date = Date.Today.AddDays(3)

    Dim day As String = Format(Today, "dddd")
    Dim time As Date
    Dim CurrHour As Integer
    Dim CurrMinute As Integer
    time = DateTime.Now
    CurrHour = time.Hour
    CurrMinute = time.Minute

    If StoreBox.Text Like "25*" Then
        MicroLabel.Visible = True

        If CurrHour >= 2 AndAlso CurrMinute >= 30 Then
            ETABox.Text = ETA2
        Else
            ETABox.Text = ETA1
        End If

    Else
        MicroLabel.Visible = False

        If CurrHour >= 2 AndAlso CurrMinute >= 30 Then
            ETABox.Text = ETA2
        Else
            ETABox.Text = ETA1
        End If

    End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DateTime` is a very flexible type which allows you to easily perform many date/time related actions. You don't need to perform a string-like analysis (what your code is doing).

For example, to take care of the two requested functionalities, just do something like:

```
Dim curTime As DateTime = Now
Dim goAhead As Boolean = True

If curTime.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday OrElse curTime.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday Then
    goAhead = False
ElseIf curTime > New DateTime(curTime.Year, curTime.Month, curTime.Day, 14, 30, 0) Then
    goAhead = False
End If

If goAhead Then
    'Weekday before 2:30 PM
End If
```

Comment: Trying this code now. Quick question tho, should the ("2:30PM") be ("2:30 PM") with a space between the 30 and PC to match the PC time exact?

Comment: @dwb does not matter. `DateTime.Parse` is very adaptable. It would take "2:30 pm", "2:30 PM", "14:30", etc. at the same level. `DateTime.TryParseExact` is a different story though.

Comment: @dwb If you are concerned about it, just use `New DateTime(curTime.Year, curTime.Month, curTime.Day, 14, 30, 0)`.

Comment: @dwb I have preferred to rely on the approach proposed by Andrew because it is an overall-valid one. My intention was showing the versatility of the DateTime type; but a so simplified approach is not reliable enough under all the possible conditions (= it was taking care just of time, but not of day; what is fine in my code but not in any code). Anyway... the whole point of my answer is showing how to face the problem, not providing you a ready-to-use code. Can you please explain me what are you testing?

Comment: Got what I needed. Thank you all!